# Variables in Latex

Tags: latex

I'm trying to use variables in latex but can't add them or subtract them. I'm
 new to LaTeX so please help me out if there is any error or any other method i can use these variables.

```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    \newcommand{\pagewidth}{17}
    \newcommand{\pageheight}{20}
    \newcommand{\strtX}{-3}
    \newcommand{\strtY}{3}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(12,10)
    \psframe(\strtX,\strtY)(\strtX+\pagewidth/2,\strtY-\pageheight/5)
    \psframe(\strtX,\strtY)(\strtX+\pagewidth/2,\strtY-\pageheight/5)
    \psframe(\strtX,\strtY)(\strtX+\pagewidth/2,\strtY-\pageheight/5)
    \psframe(\strtX,\strtY)(\strtX+\pagewidth/2,\strtY-\pageheight/5)
    \psframe(\strtX,\strtY)(\strtX+\pagewidth/2,\strtY-\pageheight/5)
    \psframe(\strtX,\strtY)(\strtX+\pagewidth/2,\strtY-\pageheight/5)
    \psframe(\strtX,\strtY)(\strtX+\pagewidth/2,\strtY-\pageheight/5)
    \psframe(\strtX,\strtY)(\strtX+\pagewidth/2,\strtY-\pageheight/5)
    \psframe(\strtX,\strtY)(\strtX+\pagewidth/2,\strtY-\pageheight/5)
    \psframe(\strtX,\strtY)(\strtX+\pagewidth/2,\strtY-\pageheight/5)
    \end{pspicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: same on TeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30081/how-can-i-sum-two-values-and-store-the-result-in-other-variable

Answer (score 2):

I don't seem to be having luck testing this.... However, I think you need to use the [`\advance`](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#advance-rp), [`\divide`](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#divide-rp), and [`\multiply`](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#multiply-rp) macros,

making this

```
\psframe(\strtX,\strtY)(\strtX+\pagewidth/2,\strtY-\pageheight/5)
```

look something like:

```
\count1=\pagewidth
\divide\count1 by 2
\advance\count1 by \strtX
\count2=\pageheight
\divide\count2 by -5
\advance\count2 by \strtY

\psframe(\strtX,\strtY)(\count1,\count2)
```

Comment: thank you. It worked but is there a macro for addition as well  as for multiply and divide???

Comment: `\advance` is the macro for addition and subtraction.